# Setting Anchor value in XAML to Left, Right, Top, Bottom

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, anchor

I want to use the WinForms DateTimePicker in my WPF project.

This works fine with the below xaml.

```
<WindowsFormsHost HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="10,10,0,-44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280">
    <wf:DateTimePicker Name="DateTimePickerBox" Dock="Fill" Anchor="Right" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

In a Winforms project if i wanted to Anchor to Left, Right, Top and Bottom i would use the below code.

```
this.dateTimePicker1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
```

How do i do this in XAML as the Anchor value will only let me assign one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use comma

```
<WindowsFormsHost HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="10,10,0,-44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280">
      <wf:DateTimePicker Name="DateTimePickerBox" Dock="Fill" Anchor="Right,Left,Bottom,Top" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Anchor="Right"` Just write **`Anchor="Top, Bottom, Left, Right"`**